# How to avoid implicit conversion for an Integer column

Tags: sql-server, optimization, execution-plan, type-conversion

```
  SELECT [BusinessEntityID],[NationalIDNumber],[LoginID],[OrganizationNode]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Employee]
  where BusinessEntityID = 5
```

[image]

I get convert_implicit() function called by SQL Server after executing the query in Actual Execution Plan.

```
  SELECT [BusinessEntityID],[NationalIDNumber],[LoginID],[OrganizationNode]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Employee]
  where BusinessEntityID = convert(int,5)
```

[image]

Obviously when I explicitly convert the Scalar value to Integer type, convert_implicit() function is not called. Is there any way we can avoid implicit conversion for a scalar int value without using the explicit conversion. Also I would like to know the performance difference between implicit conversion ,explicit conversion and no conversion happened at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to avoid implicit conversion for an Integer column

It is the **parameter** that has been implicitly converted, not the column.

The query has been subject to [Simple Parameterization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186219(v=sql.105).aspx) by SQL Server. You have no control over the datatypes used in this process. It uses the smallest datatype that can hold the literal value (`5` can fit into a `tinyint`). The implicit cast of a `tinyint` parameter to an `int` won't cause any problems.

However to avoid having multiple plans in cache for `int`, `smallint`, `tinyint` and get rid of the implicit cast you could explicitly parameterize the query yourself - with a parameter of datatype `int` rather than having it be parameterized automatically.

```
EXEC sys.sp_executesql
  N'SELECT [BusinessEntityID],[NationalIDNumber],[LoginID],[OrganizationNode]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Employee]
  where BusinessEntityID = @BusinessEntityID',
  N'@BusinessEntityID INT',
  @BusinessEntityID = 5;
```

One other alternative would be to block simple parameterisation by adding a redundant `AND 1=1` as below. But I don't recommend this as then you will get plans compiled and cached for every different literal value that you pass.

```
SELECT [BusinessEntityID],
       [NationalIDNumber],
       [LoginID],
       [OrganizationNode]
FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Employee]
where BusinessEntityID = 5 
      AND 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Use a variable, you will also get the benefits of query reuse

```
Declare @ BeID int = 5
select xxx where BuisnessEntityID = @BeID
```

If you want to be certain you need to strongly type the query, either by using a variable or by using `cast/convert`:

```
select xxx where BuisnessEntityID = CAST (5 as int)
```

I think the performance overhead of the implicit conversion there is negligible - but there I might be wrong. But by using a variable you will definitely get the benefits of query cache reuse.

Comment: After seeing you comment, I've just realized that as long as I actually use the variables when setting the queries (in the ORM), I do not actually get this issue - while, when I would take the already-built query and just paste it into the SQL manager, for purpose of debugging it and checking the execution plan, then I don't use the variables/parameters and hence I get a false positive report that this query really does the implicit conversion. So, apparently, there may be no problem at all.